# Days of the week from Start Time

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar, sharepoint-email

I'm creating a team calendar to send alerts a day before a set activity takes place.

I have currently got it working for 1 day in advance with no issues (regardless of day) using the following flow:

```
Stage:emailReminder
Add 0 months, -1 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes to Current Item:Start Time (Output to Variable: reminderDate )
Pause until Variable: reminderDate
Email Alex; 
Transition to stage
Go to End of Workflow
```

I'm trying to get it so that on a Saturday it will send the e-mail 1 day before so Friday, then Sunday 2 days before (Again Friday) and then on Monday 3 days before (again Friday)

My understanding would be that I need to convert Current Item:Start Time into a string and check if it contains Saturday, Sunday or Monday. I've given it a go using the following flow (leaving out Monday's -3):

```
  Stage:Stage 1
Set Variable: todaysDate to Today
Set Variable: longDateString to Variable: todaysDate
If Variable: longDateString contains Saturday
    Add 0 months, -1 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes to Current Item:Start Time (Output to Variable: reminderDate )
    Pause until Variable: reminderDate
    Email Alex 
Else
    If Variable: longDateString contains Sunday
        Add 0 months, -2 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes to Current Item:Start Time (Output to Variable: reminderDate )
        Pause until Variable: reminderDate
        Email Alex 
    Else
        Add 0 months, -1 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes to Current Item:Start Time (Output to Variable: reminderDate )
        Pause until Variable: reminderDate
        Email Alex 
Transition to stage
Go to End of Workflow
```

I think that the above one isn't working because i have tried to follow another guide and implement it into my current working flow and i'm using different variable names - I've completely lost myself basically! I'm pretty certain my If/Else works okay but i've got in a muddle at the start and with the converting to days of the week